# Guest customer is redirected to login page after add product to cart

Tags: customer, login, addtocart

I want to enable guest checkout Yes. So if customer is not logged in then also he can redirected to cart page.

For this I tried to change value of Allow Guest Checkout to Yes at System > Configuration > Sales section > Checkout > Checkout Options

But there is not effect.

I am using magento 1.9.0.1

Comment: Are you adding a downloadable/virtual product to cart?

Comment: Virtual Product

Answer (score 0):

Since you need an account to use or download the virtual product this is actually correct.

A user need to be registered to consume this type of product from My Account.